# Vue import with relative project root path in test folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

I want to use a helper object/function in a Jest test with Vue test-utils, where I have a `tests` folder on my project root.

> `unitMocks.js` in tests/unit/unitMocks.js

```
export const mockComputed = {
  products() {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  },
  activities() {
    return [4, 5, 6];
  },
  ....
};

export const mockGetterProduct = () => {
...
```

> `Dashboard.spec.js` in tests/unit/views/

```
import Dashboard from "@/views/Dashboard.vue";
import { mockComputed } from "../unitMocks.js";
...

describe("Dashboard.vue", () => {
...
```

To import this, I want to avoid using a relative path (`../unitMocks.js`) so I was wondering how to access the relative root path.

I'm aware of the [babel root import plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-root-import) and I also tried to modify the webpack alias of my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        tests: "tests/"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

..but my test still won't find that file when I import it.

Isn't there a **native** way of accessing the root path (like `@` for `src`)? Is this related to Webpack or Babel?

Comment: In webpack.base.conf.js, you can add another symbol that resolves to tests folder. You should add it inside resolve: {alias: {}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack's `resolve.alias` can be accomplished in Jest configuration with [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-object-string-string). Specifically, to add a `tests` alias mapped to `<rootDir>/tests/`, add the following to `jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^tests/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/tests/$1',
},
```

Then, you could import `tests/unit/foo.json` from your test scripts like this:

```
// In tests/x/y/z/example.spec.js
import foo from 'tests/unit/foo.json';
```